# Installing an FPS game in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, games

I just got started with Ubuntu a few months back and I am kind of enjoying it. However, I would like to play some games in Ubuntu like Hitman, Delta Force, COD, etc. You get the type of game: I think it's called FPS. So can you guys just pick one game of your choice and give me the steps you followed to install it.

I have read a few answers in some forums but I am unable to wrap by head around it. 
All I could understand was 
Step 1 : Install Wine (Completed)
Step 2 : Install Steam ???
...

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
You can install Steam from the software center and do not need to install wine for it.

Many games like Counter Strike : Global Offensive etc work natively on Linux.

2.
Otherwise, you can install open source FPS like Assault Cube using the Terminal.

`sudo apt-get install assaultcube`

3.
You can also run windows games using PlayOnLinux. To install -

`sudo apt-get install playonlinux`

Comment: "Many games like Counter Strike : Global Offensive" Well... CSGO is not without bugs, CS Source works flawlessly.

Comment: In Ubuntu Software Center there are two options 
Steam(Steam)-Application for managing and playing games on steam
Steam(Steam Launcher)-The ultimate platform for installing steam
Which one should I install?
After installing steam then what? I am new to Linux so please excuse my ignorance

Comment: Install the `steam-launcher` package.

Comment: Installed the steam launcher. Do I need to be online if I want to play games?

Comment: It depends on whether you want to play online or offline. Most games can be played offline. However, some games require that you are always online.

Comment: Can you please help me get started with steam by telling me how to install a game? Its a bit overwhelming. I have just recently made a switch to Ubuntu.